# remesh or retoplogy, maybe specific tool?

Tags: edit-mode, topology, retopology, remesh

Still a beginner here. I have this cloth pattern and I cannot seem to find a good way to automatically obtain a good topology on it. Anyone knows of a good method for this case?(screenshot attached) I tried remesh but it only gives me very weird shapes. I used knife tool and proportional editing to get to this stage of deformations. I would really appreciate any advice! [image]

Comment: What constitutes "good" topology changes from one end-use to the next, and can be sufficiently opinion-based for this to be an inappropriate question here.  My fave topology links are over here: https://blenderartists.org/t/topology-understanding-and-poles/1248035/3 .  For this ask, editing it to add more details on what you intend to do with that could be helpful.  Also, it's often a good idea to post your blend file, or a truncated version of it that includes the issue.  The Blender StackExchange has its own service to share blend files:  https://blend-exchange.com/help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one example of a “good” (all-quads, no poles less than 3 or greater than 5, no poles on creased or tightly curved areas, even polygon distribution, loops [shown in blue and orange] follow real-world function) for a garment similiar to what your screenshot shows:

[image]

[image]

With its included add-ons [F2](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/addons/mesh/f2.html), [Loop Tools](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/addons/mesh/looptools.html), and [Bsurfaces GPL Edition](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.1/addons/mesh/bsurfaces.html) enabled Blender is sufficient for general (but not automatic) topology and retopology needs.  Recommendations for external or commercial add-ons can run afoul of BSE's rule against opinion-based questions and answers, but [this topic at BlenderArtists may be helpful](https://blenderartists.org/t/good-retopology-addon/1291482).

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers! Very much appreciated !

Comment: Hope it was helpful!  If I've answered your question then please click the checkmark next to my answer.